# What is the parent layout of All Root layout in Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, parent-child, android-framelayout, gravity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

My Java Code:

```
linearLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
System.out.println(linearLayout.getParent());
```

it will show you framelayout is the parent layout of linear layout.please tell
1. how frame layout is the parent layout of linear layout?
2. by Default window has frame layout?

Please help me.thanks in advance.

Comment: ad 1 FrameLayout can be a parent of any View including LinearLayout,  ad 2 check it: Window.getDecorView()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, `DecorView` will use a `FrameLayout` to store all the content set by applications. You can read the source of [`PhoneWindow`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/3bdbf644d61f46b531838558fabbd5b990fc4913/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindow.java)

Comment: Thanks suitaianshi.can you send me a link/source so where i can get more knowledge about decorview.theoretical content not a progmatical content

Comment: Sorry that I can't find one (good enough) article about it. But I always think that the source code is the best tutorial.